# Regex for a positive decimal or an integer string up to 7 characters in length

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex for a RegularExpressionValidator Control that will allow a decimal or integer with the following conditions:

- Cannot be negative
- Has no leading or trailing zeros
- Maximum string length including the optional decimal point is 7 characters
- Maximum number of decimal places is 2

A solitary zero is allowed

So these are good....

```
0
0.1
0.12
1.34
12.45
123.67
1234.67
12345.7
```

and these are bad.....

```
-0
-0.1
012.4
123.560
123...7
```

could someone advise on this please. i've had a few attempts and the main component i'm struggling with is checking for just one decimal point. thank you

Comment: If `maximum number of decimal places is 2` then how come `123.567` is allowed?

Comment: sorry that was a typo - there can only be 2 characters after the decimal point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following regex should work for you:

```
(?!^0[1-9])(?=^([0-9])+(\.\d{1,2}(?<!0))?$)^.{1,7}$
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/Y3wVkKST1I

Comment: Try 1204 - it doesn't match but it should

Comment: @user9876: Thanks, that was a good point. I edited my answer.

Comment: Apologies but there was an error in my good list. There can only be two characters after the decimal point. Therefore 123.567 should be in the bad list. How would I tweak the explanation to meet this criteria?

Comment: @PaulStevens: I have already taken care of that in my latest edit. Check the rubular link for demo where `123.567` is not matched.

Comment: @anubhava: Could you help with this one please. I've been trying to tweak this using a regex tester to create two new versions so the same rules apply, but one is a human height field in metres so the maximum, to two decimal places, would be 9.99 (max 4 characters), and the second field is a weight field in kilos so the maximum, to three decimal places, would be 999.999 (max 7 characters).

Comment: @PaulStevens: That appears to be a little different problem. I suggest you to create a new Question on SO by providing link to this question and state your problem clearly. Please leave a comment here with the link to the new question. I will be more than happy to provide answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it, without look-behinds:

```
^(?=.{1,7}$)(0(?=\.|$)|[1-9])\d*(\.\d?[1-9])?$
```

See a [live demo on rubular](http://rubular.com/r/WK1YQaVqFt)